# Ecto.Multi ussage

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my Phoenix app I have the following schemas:

```
defmodule TattooBackend.Accounts.Account do
  schema "accounts" do
    field :email, :string
    field :crypted_password, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_confirmation, :string, virtual: true

    timestamps()
  end
end

defmodule TattooBackend.Accounts.Studio do
  schema "studios" do
    field :name, :string

    belongs_to :account, Account

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

Now I'm trying to write code for inserting Account and Studio to the database in one transaction. I'm using Ecto.Multi for doing that. My code looks like this:

```
multi = Multi.new |>
Multi.insert(:account, Account.changeset(%Account{}, %{email: "test@email.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password"})) |>
Multi.run(:studio, fn %{account: account} ->
  studio_changeset = Studio.changeset(%Studio{}, %{name: "test", account_id: account.id})
  Repo.insert(studio_changeset)
end)

Repo.transaction(multi)
```

This code works perfectly fine, but I'm wondering if there is any place to make it better. I'm still pretty new to Elixir so I want to know if something can be done in better way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using `Multi.run/3` instead of another `Multi.insert/4`?

Comment: @JustinWood I used Multi.run because I need to update Studio changeset account_id value after Account creation. Or maybe there is way of doing that using Multi.insert?

Comment: You are right. I didn't realize you couldn't get the current changes with `Multi.insert/4`.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular code, you use `put_assoc` to put the new `Studio` in `Account` and then do `Repo.insert!`:

```
Account.changeset(%Account{}, %{email: "test@email.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password"})
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:studios, [Studio.changeset(%Studio{}, %{name: "test"})])
|> Repo.insert!
```

`put_assoc` will handle putting the correct `account_id` in the `Studio` before it is inserted and the two inserts will also automatically be run in one transaction.

Comment: The following code: ```Account.changeset(%Account{}, %{email: "test@email.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password"})|>
  Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:studio, [Studio.changeset(%Studio{}, %{name: "test"})]) |>
  Repo.insert
```

Returns error: 
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in anonymous fn/2 in Ecto.Changeset.get_changed/6

Comment: Does `Account` have `has_many :studios, TattooBackend.Accounts.Studio`? If not, please
 try adding that and then change `:studio` to `:studios` in `put_assoc`.

Comment: `Account` have `has_one :studio, Studio`

Comment: Ah, I thought it was `has_many`. For `has_one` this should work: `Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:studio, Studio.changeset(%Studio{}, %{name: "test"}))`.

Comment: Unfortunately this still not works. This returns me an error: ```errors: [account_id: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}]```

Comment: Ah, so `account_id` is required in Studio. You probably need to make the Studio changeset first and then `put_assoc(:account, Account.changeset(...))`.